# Time based PHP greetings

Tags: php, datetime, time, message

I have a simple PHP time based message script (based on the users local time). It's not working as I had imagined, not quite sure what is wrong.

I'm basically looking for these messages at these times:

1. 3am - 6am  - Message 1
2. 6am - 12pm - Message 2
3. 12pm - 3pm - Message 3
4. 3pm - 6pm  - Message 4
5. 6pm - 8pm  - Message 5
6. 8pm - 10pm - Message 6
7. 10pm -12am - Message 7
8. 12am - 3am - Message 8

I have this code already:

```
    <?php

    $b = time();

    $hour = date("g", $b);
    $m    = date("A", $b);

    if ($m == "AM") {
      if ($hour == 12) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
      } elseif ($hour < 4) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
      } elseif ($hour > 3) {
        echo "Good Morning!";
      }
    }

        elseif ($m == "PM") {
      if ($hour == 12) {
        echo "Good Afternoon!";
      } elseif ($hour < 6) {
        echo "Good Afternoon!";
      } elseif ($hour > 5) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
      }
    }

    ?>
```

This is okay, but it seems to be an hour ahead of what I expected, I'm assuming this is because it's reading GMT, whereas the UK is currently in BST (GMT+1). If that can't be fixed, that's not a problem as I can just adjust the hour accordingly. When I try to add the additional times I require messages for though, I have been getting some strange results. I'm new to PHP, so any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What are the results you are getting?

Comment: And what *do* you want to get? Should all users get UK time? Is your server's timezone configured correctly? Have you looked into [localtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php)?

Comment: `based on the users local time`, not going to happen. Your need to ask beforehand what timezone the user is in, or do all this with javascript.

Comment: It's not displaying the correct messages at the correct times. I tried adding the extra messages like so:

 `if ($hour == 12) {
        echo "Message 3";
      } elseif ($hour < 3) {
        echo "Message 3";
      } elseif ($hour > 3) {
        echo "Message 4";
      } elseif ($hour < 6) {
        echo "Message 4";
      } elseif ($hour > 6  {
        echo "Message 5";
      } elseif ($hour < 8  {
        echo "Message 5";
      }
      }`

Thanks

Comment: Was hoping to avoid Javascript. But will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: PHP is server side, so you'll have to ask the user what timezone (s)he's in. This could be saved in a user's account, in a session or in a cookie. Either way, settings like time will reflect your server's settings, not the client's. Changing your server's timezone according to the user's would be a bad idea, as it would screw up any logging and other time dependant functions

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to set your default time zone.  Here is a handy script straight from the PHP docs...

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
```

A list of all supported time zones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

And if i remember correctly you only need to run it once to set the time zone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels'); //added line
    $b = time();

    $hour = date("g", $b);
    $m    = date("A", $b);

    if ($m == "AM") {
      if ($hour == 12) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
      } elseif ($hour < 4) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
      } elseif ($hour > 3) {
        echo "Good Morning!";
      }
    }

        elseif ($m == "PM") {
      if ($hour == 12) {
        echo "Good Afternoon!";
      } elseif ($hour < 6) {
        echo "Good Afternoon!";
      } elseif ($hour > 5) {
        echo "Good Evening!";
      }
    }

    ?>
```